# Auto Translate Page With Google Tool Based on IP or Locale?

Tags: google-translate, machine-translation, google-translator-toolkit

I currently have the [Google Website Translator](https://translate.google.com/manager/website/suggestions) installed on my website. However would like it to activate automatically based on:

1. Visitor's IP
2. Visitor's Locale
3. Both

I googled about it, but couldn't find anything, probably because the keywords are so common: auto translation etc.